A subgroup of the direct product of two groups
Assume that we have two groups $G$ and $H$ generated respectively by the sets $S_G$ and $S_H$. Also assume that $S_G$ and $S_H$ have the same cardinality. $i_G$ and $i_H$ are the identity elements of $G$ and $H$, while $\circ_G$ and $\circ_H$ are their respective group operators.
Consider the set $K:=(S_G\times\{i_H\})\cup(\{i_G\}\times S_H)$. This set, along with the component-wise operator defined as $(a,b)\circ (c,d)=(a\circ_G c, b\circ_H d)$, generates the direct product of the two groups $G\times H$.
 
However, this is not the only way to combine the two generating sets $S_G$ and $S_H$. Here is another approach:
Since $|S_G|=|S_H|$, we can build a bijection $R:S_G\rightarrow S_H$. Now, defining, $$S_G\star_R S_H:=\{(g,h)\mid g\in S_G \land h\in S_H \land R(g)=h\}$$
Effectively, this ‘pairs up’ elements of $K$, by composing them. So this new set has half the cardinality of the generating set $K$.

For example, suppose $S_G=\{a,b\}$ and $S_H=\{x,y\}$. In this case, $K=\{(a,i_H),(b,i_H),(i_G,x), (i_G,y)\}$. This set, along with the component-wise composition operator described previously, generates $G\times H$
If we choose the ‘pairing up’ $S_G \star_R S_H=\{(a,x),(b,y)\}$, we are simply taking the original generating set $K$ and composing the 1st and 3rd elements together to get $(a,x)$ and the 2nd and 4th elements together to get $(b,y)$

The set $S_G\star_R S_H$, along with the operator $\circ$ (as defined previously), generates a new group which we can denote as $G \star_R H$
$G\star_R H$ depends upon the chosen generating sets for each group and the bijection $R$ which ‘pairs up’ elements from the two generating sets.
As has been noted in the chat and the comments below, $G\star_R H$ is a subgroup of the direct product $G\times H$
I am looking for more information about this type of subgroup of the direct product between two groups.

Possible application
Consider the infinite dihedral group $\mathrm{Dih}_\infty$ and the infinite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}$.
Choose the presentation $\langle r,s\mid s^2=1,srs=r^{-1}\rangle$ for $\mathrm{Dih}_\infty$ group, thus getting the generating set $\{r,s\}$
Choose $\{0,1\}$ as a generating set for $\mathbb{Z}$ along with addition as the group operator.
We can pair up the two generating sets to create a new set $W=\{(r,0),(s,1)\}$, which corresponds to a bijection $R$ from $\{r,s\}$ to $\{0,1\}$. The set $W$ generates the wallpaper group $\mathrm{pg}$, where the first element corresponds to the vertical translation symmetry and the second element corresponds to the horizontal glide symmetry. Thus the group $\mathrm{pg}$ can be shown isomorphic to $\mathrm{Dih}_\infty\star_R\mathbb{Z}$.

Another Example
We have chosen $\mathrm{K4}$ (Klein-4 group) and $\mathrm{D3}$ (symmetry group of equilateral triangle) to demonstrate $\mathrm{K4}\star_R\mathrm{D3}$
Chosen presentations:
For $\mathrm{K4}$, from here:
$$\langle x,y \mid x^2 = y^2 = (xy)^2 = 1 \rangle$$

For $\mathrm{D3}$, from here:
$$\langle a,b \mid a^3= b^2 = 1, ab = ba^{-1} \rangle$$

Thereby we get the generating sets $\{x,y\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ respectively.
We choose the following pairing, to get a new generating set $\{(x,a),(y,b)\}$, and its corresponding bijection $R$. We can use this generating set, along with the composition operator as described previously to get $\mathrm{K4}\star_R\mathrm{D3}$

As we can see, $\mathrm{K4}\star_R\mathrm{D3}$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{D6}$, a subgroup of direct product $\mathrm{K4}\times\mathrm{D3}$

Edit:
Discussed further in this chat
Edit #2:
I have tried to clarify my original question, but there may still be issues that I have overlooked. All suggestions on how to improve this post are welcome.

It looks a bit like an amalgamated free product, but of a direct product.  I doubt it's new.

Also, the construction is not at all clear.

@Shaun Could you elaborate on which part of the construction you find unclear?

If I understand correctly, the elements of $\mathrm{Dih}\infty\star\mathbb{Z}$ will look like $(g,n)$ with $g\in \mathrm{Dih}\infty$ and $n\in \Bbb Z$. And the operation is done component-wise. So, isn't this just $\mathrm{Dih}_\infty\times\mathbb{Z}$?

What is its operation?

The RHS of $$S_G\star S_H:={(g,h)\mid g\in S_G \land h\in S_H \land R(g)=h}
$$ depends on $R$ when the LHS does not.

The more I think about this, the more I find wrong with it.  Have you proven it's a group?

All you've done is introduce a bijection.

I think it would be better to continue in the chat

Isn't this just a subgroup of the direct product? If so I don't think it's a 'A new type of group product' or needs new notation, but I think it can be studied.

You can't say "generates a new group" without first specifying either (a) the containing group where it will be a subgroup, or (b) proving it is a group (associative, closed under products, containing inverses).

@SteveD I had not previously noticed that the "product" that I was defining was a subgroup of the direct product, as has been observed in the chat and by Keplerto in the comments. I will update the post to include this.

@Keplerto yes, I think so too after discussing in the chat. I will update the post

What you have is a subdirect product of $G\times H$; they are classified by Goursat's Lemma.

@ArturoMagidin I have not yet learnt about Goursat’s Lemma. Still, thanks a lot for providing the reference, I will read about the topic.
